# Set up NTP server on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ntp

How can I make an iOS device a NTP server ? The reason for this is, the network of devices I have don't have internet connection but are connected via Wifi. So just want to create a device as a server and let others to associate themselves to it.

Comment: However the iOS device won't be running all the tie so how does that help. In this case I would find a small server e.g. Raspberry, Ardinuo etc

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote two answers from Stack Overflow with the hope that it will help you figure out what you're trying to do.

---

There's a small iOS library named [ios-ntp](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp). I have used it in one project in the past and it seemed to work reasonably well.

As of mid 2013 the original ios-ntp project has a few missing pieces, so I have mirrored the original svn repository to github. You can checkout out a working version of the code here: https://github.com/jessedc/iOS-ntp

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4121208/2599996)

---

If you're not developing a commercial application, peek at the linux source.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/lucid/ntp

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313390/2599996)

---

[Thread source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i have seen them already and they doesn't seem to solve my purpose. The ios-ntp library makes us get the time through the standard time servers, however I need to create a ntp server of my own because I don't have access to internet. Want to create some sort of master slave architecture, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I will search around. I can't promise much, but whatever I find will be posted here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just use dns to intercept requests to time.apple.com and point to a local Linux or raspi serving ntp.  Of course, you will need to set up a dns for this to work.

Comment: I don't see how this directly answers the question.